# Gerund, infinitive or root form

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, bare-infinitives

“Once you crossed the whole camp on foot, **asking** for a glass of water is not a surprise”.

I used the gerund (asking) because it sounds to me like the correct form in this case, once I couldn’t find an explanation which helped.

Should I have used simply “ask” or “to ask” instead?

Moreover, when I add an adverb to the sentence, I feel like I should use the root form (bare infinitive, without “to”) of the verb:

“Once you crossed the whole camp on foot, *politely* **ask** for a glass of water is not a surprise”.

Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second clause of your sentence contains the verb **is**, so it requires a noun clause as a subject. A simpler example would be

> riding **is** fun

There are two choices of noun form for a verb- a gerund or a to-infinitive. In some special cases, you should use a bare infinitive, but this isn't one of them.

[This article](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/gerund-vs-infinitive-practice) explains how you should choose between gerund or to-infinitive. In this case, it revolves around whether you are talking about a real or a hypothetical situation. Unfortunately, the tenses in your sentence are a bit mixed up, so it's difficult to tell whether it's real or hypothetical. Let's make two grammatically correct versions, one for gerund and another for to-infinitive:

> After you crossed the whole camp on foot, asking for a glass of water was not a surprise. - *real, past*
>
> If you were to cross the whole camp on foot, to ask for a glass of water would not be a surprise. - *hypothetical*

Adding an adverb does not change at all the type of verb to use:

> After you crossed the whole camp on foot, **hurriedly** asking for a glass of water was not a surprise. - *real, past*